# How to view docker compose logs while using dev container on vscode

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-devcontainer

I am running dev containers on my project that utilizes `docker-compose` for multiple containers.
My issue is that I cannot view my docker-compose logs. I am not sure how to access it.

Inside the folder `.devcontainer` I have two files:

1. `devcontainer.json`:

   ```json
       {
            "name": "TrendR",
            "dockerComposeFile": [
                "../docker-compose.yml",
                "docker-compose.yml"
            ],

            "service": "api",

            "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",

            "settings": {
                "python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python",
                "python.linting.enabled": true,
                "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
            },

            "extensions": ["ms-python.python","ms-azuretools.vscode-docker"]

        }
   ```
2. `docker-compose.yml`:

   ```yaml
       version: '3.8'
       services:
          api:
            volumes:
               - .:/workspace:cached
               - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 

            command: /bin/sh -c "while sleep 1000; do :; done"
   ```

This is the main docker-compose.yml inside the project folder.

```yaml
    version: "3.8"
    
    services:
        db:
            container_name: db
            image: postgres:13
            ports:
                - "5433:5432"
            environment:
                - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
                - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
                - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
            volumes:
                - /var/lib/postgresql/data
    
        api:
            build:
                context: ./api/
                dockerfile: Dockerfile
            volumes:
                - ./api/app:/app/app
            ports:
                - "1000:80"
            depends_on:
                - db
            env_file:
                - .env
            command: ["/start-reload.sh"]
            labels:
                - "traefik.enable=true"
                - "traefik.http.routers.${API_SUBDOMAIN}.rule=Host(`${API_SUBDOMAIN}.${DOMAIN}`)"
    
        frontend:
            build:
                context: ./frontend/
                dockerfile: Dockerfile
            ports:
                - "3000:3000"
            volumes:
                - /app/node_modules
                - ./frontend:/app
            environment:
                - NODE_ENV=development
            stdin_open: true
            links:
                - api
            labels:
                - "traefik.enable=true"
                - "traefik.http.routers.${CLIENT_SUBDOMAIN}.rule=Host(`${CLIENT_SUBDOMAIN}.${DOMAIN}`)"
    
        redis:
            container_name: trendr_redis
            image: "redis:alpine"
            ports:
                - "6379:6379"
    
        traefik:
            image: traefik:v2.4
            ports:
                - "80:80"
                - "8080:8080"
            volumes:
                - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
                - "$PWD/traefik/traefik.dev.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you open a terminal and run `docker-compose up` in the same location as the docker-compose file you should see your logs

Comment: They disappear. Only a few lines are visible at each time.